# How to make a price range slider from get_post_meta?

Tags: posts

How can I make a price range slider from get_post_meta?

I'm getting the post price's as:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID,'price' ,true);
```

I want to put this for example in to [THIS](https://codepen.io/fstgerm/pen/XyWGZB) slider:

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.